# console.log avoid maximum call stack

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8

Code below got error `Maximum call stack size exceeded` as expected.

```
function recurrent (i = 0) {
  recurrent(++i)
}

recurrent ()
```

**I expect this exceeded the maximum call stack, too.
However, it runs, why?**

```
function recurrent (i = 0) {
  console.log(i)
  recurrent(++i)
}

recurrent ()
```

Result:

print till a number and **stop**, but no errors.

```
...
10815
10816
10817
10818
10819
10820
10821
10822
10823
10824
```

I'm using NodeJs 10 on Windows 10

#### Update

Chrome got error 
[image]

Comment: Did you run the second snippet enough time. I believe, that eventually, you will see the same error.

Comment: I will print till around `108xx` and stop, no errors.

Comment: What OS are you using? I'm using Node 10 on MacOS and I'm seeing the expected result of `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`, as in my answer.

Comment: I got **error: too much recursion** after running it a while on the **Developer Console** of **Firefox 68.0.1 (64 bits)**.

Comment: @Shidersz That's essentially the same error. You're quite literally getting a _stack overflow_.

Comment: I've updated my post, I'm using Win10.

Comment: @ajxs Yes, indeed, that's why I pointed to run the second example enough time.

Comment: @Shidersz Pardon me, I didn't notice that you were the first commenter! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They'll both fail in the exact same way, as one would expect. It's just that the log statement slows the function down to a degree that it may not appear to fail *immediately*.

Here's the results of timing each version using `time`:

```
# With logging:
...
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

real    0m0.204s
user    0m0.171s
sys 0m0.035s
```

```
# Without logging
...
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

real    0m0.082s
user    0m0.054s
sys 0m0.021s
```

When testing this in Chrome the same process occurs, however much, much slower. It took over 30 seconds before the `RangeError` was thrown.